Unindent and convert multiline string to single line
I have several multiline strings with indentation in my code, such as this (simplified example):
def foo():
    cmd = '''ls
                 /usr/bin
                 /usr/sbin
                 /usr/local/bin'''
    print(f'{cmd=}')

foo()

I want to remove indentation and unwrap such strings for printing them as a single line each. Currently, it prints also newline characters and whitespace that results from the indents:
cmd='ls\n                 /usr/bin\n                 /usr/sbin\n                 /usr/local/bin'


Replace multiple occurrences of whitespace (including newlines, tabs and blanks) with a single blank using re.sub:
import re

def foo():
    cmd = re.sub(
        r'\s+', ' ',
        '''ls
              /usr/bin
              /usr/sbin
              /usr/local/bin''')
    print(f'{cmd=}')

foo()

Prints:
cmd='ls /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/local/bin'

